# Lost all my current data after last restart-Neo4j 2.3.2

Tags: neo4j

I am using `neo4j 2.3.2`(upgraded from `2.1.8`) in embedded mode with a `JAVAEE` application. My problem is whenever I do an application and server restart I lose all the data I have recently saved. Below is my property configuration I am using. It is running on a 8GB server.

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
dbms.pagecache.memory=2g
```

Below is the code(Servlet) I am using to get input in the form of xml into the graph database after i send an ack to salesforce

```
  String theString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                log.info("Salesforce data/n " + theString);
                //gets request input stream

   Transaction tx = null;

        try {

            log.info(" " + request.getContentType());
            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            Map<String,String> update = new HashMap<>();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(theString));


        System.out.println("After parsing XML");
            Document doc = db.parse(is);  
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            Element ele = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();

           log.info("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement());

            //get fields from xml objects
            NodeList sObject = doc.getElementsByTagName("sObject");
            tx = ICTCDBUtil.getInstance().getGraphDB().beginTx();
            for (int j = 0; j < sObject.getLength(); j++) {

                Node rowNode = sObject.item(j);
                String salesforceObj = 

    rowNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("xsi:type").getNodeValue();
                        log.info(salesforceObj);

                      if (salesforceObj.equalsIgnoreCase("sf:Farmer_Biodata__c")) {
                            farmerID = getXmlNodeValue("sf:Id",ele);
                            agentId = getXmlNodeValue("sf:CreatedById",ele);
                            bb = biodataModel.getBiodata("Id", farmerID);


                            if(null!=bb )
                            {

                                log.info("Farmer Already Exist Id " + farmerID);
                                out.println(sendAck());



                               }
                           else
                           {



                     org.neo4j.graphdb.Node biodataNode = ICTCDBUtil.getInstance().getGraphDB().createNode();
                        biodataNode.addLabel(Labels.FARMER);
  for (int k = 0; k < rowNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); k++) {

                               // System.out.println("node: " + rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName() + ": " + rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getTextContent());
                                if (rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName().equals("sf:Id") ||rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName().equals("sf:CreatedById") ) {
                                    log.info("id : " + getObjectFieldId(rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName()));

                                    biodataNode.setProperty(getObjectFieldId(rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName()), rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getTextContent());
                                }

                                if (!rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName().equals("sf:Id") && !rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName().equals("#text") && !rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName().equals("sf:CreatedById")) {

                                    log.info(getObjectFieldName(rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName()));
                                    biodataNode.setProperty(getObjectFieldName(rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeName()), rowNode.getChildNodes().item(k).getTextContent());

                                }
                            }

              biodataNode.setProperty(Biodata.LAST_MODIFIED,new Date().getTime());
              log.log(Level.INFO, "new node created {0}", biodataNode.getId());


                            out.println(sendAck());


                           }


                          tx.success();

                         } 

                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {      Logger.getLogger(SaleforceIntegrationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    tx.failure();
                } finally {
                    tx.close();
                }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to start / connect to the database?

Comment: Hi William.I am loading the properties from a file hence the code below--------  graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().setUserLogProvider(new Slf4jLogProvider())
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DATABASE_PATH)
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_store_upgrade, dbProperties.getProperty("allow_store_upgrade"))
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, dbProperties.getProperty("dbms.pagecache.memory"))
                .newGraphDatabase();    registerShutdownHook(graphdb);
    
       return  graphdb;

Comment: I get this  message when neo4j shutsdown created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool.MuninnReadPageCursorThreadLocal] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool$MuninnReadPageCursorThreadLocal@77572b38]) and a value of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnReadPageCursor] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnReadPageCursor@7d82af05]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Comment: did you take a backup before? please upgrade via neo4j-2.2. e.g. by running bin/neo4j-shell -path data/graph.db -config conf/neo4j.properties -c quit

Comment: can you share any errors from graph.db/messages.log ?

Comment: graph.db/messages.log  does not show any errors.Could not backup when the server was running using community edition in embedded mode(backup can be done when server is shutdown)

Comment: How is the data imported from Salesforce, e.g. what does that code look like? (if you don't mind sharing).

Could it be that the data is batched into bigger transactions or some other intermediary data structure and isn't actually imported until later? Or that transactions that import data aren't closed properly? Is all imported data imported by the same thread or some sort of thread pool?

Comment: @MattiasPersson i have added the code to the question and also the code runs in a servlet  that gets the xml data from salesforce after users have made a submission to salesforce so i think each submission or import is done on a seperate thread

Comment: Can't see anything terribly suspicious in the code though, the transaction is closed in a finally block and success() is called, although once in every iteration of the loop and inside a condition, but that's where any db changes takes place anyway. You're sending an ack back before the transaction has been committed though (potentially many per request even), but I doubt that should affect things too much either.